# Is name Angloher derived from Anglii from northern Germany?

Tags: germany, surnames

Is the name Angloher tied to the Anglii from northern Germany? Would this mean that the name would then be a derivative of a Herr of Anglii? Or Angels?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surname derivation from the Angle tribe, once based in northern Germany, is unlikely.

1. The highest concentration of Angloher residents of Germany per [Geogen](http://geogen.stoepel.net/) is in south-east Bavaria, near the Austrian border. An origin in local vocabulary is most likely.
2. The word ending "er" implies belonging to or having connections to something or somewhere. As it happens, there is a placename "[Angloh](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/ANGLOH_W8399)" not far from Bad Füssing in the high concentration region identified in point 1.

Angloher most likely derives from "the man from Angloh."