# History of German small town of Angloh?

Tags: germany, research-methods, historical-gazetteer, bavaria, 15th-century

I found the town of Angloh in Germany but nothing is left of it other than a spa.

I tried searching for weeks throughout the web but couldn't find anything about it other than coordinates.

How do I find established and history on a forgotten town like this?

**Full Name (see definition): Angloh
Primary Country Code (see definition): GM (Germany)
First-order administrative division code (see definition): 02 (Bayern )
Region Font Code (see definition): 1 (Americas/Western Europe)
Unique Feature Identifier (see definition): -1740505
Unique Name Identifier (see definition): -2437399
Latitude in decimal degrees (see definition): 48.333333
Longitude in decimal degrees (see definition): 13.283333
Latitude in degrees, minutes, and seconds (see definition): 48° 20' 00" N
Longitude in degrees, minutes, and seconds (see definition): 13° 17' 00" E
Military Grid Reference System coordinates (see definition): 33UUP7277454774**

Comment: Do you have a link to the coordinates of Anglo (or is it Angloh?) that you can include as an [edit] to your question?  Is it perhaps http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/ANGLOH_W8399 from http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9640/19?

Comment: Acronym finder returned 232 meanings for SPA -- could you clarify please?

Comment: @Jan Murphy - it's not an acronym (in this case) - he's just using all caps. The area around Angloh is a government-accredited rehabilitation area.

Comment: SPA was supposed to read Spa. It is a place where steam or hot natural springs are used as a wellness and recuperative place.

Answer (score 6):

**Technique**
Generally when you cannot find information on very small or insignificant placenames, you research nearby larger places (because events may apply to a larger area) or the next placename in the hierarchy. You may even get lucky and find passing references to your main interest that weren't directly searchable.

**Scope**
Angloh (var. Angerloh) is officially part of Kirchham, so searching the history of that city would be first. Also Landkreis Passau and its predecessors and Bavaria.

**Resources**
Don't restrict yourself to on-line searches. Check library and archive catalogues for hard-copy histories and digitized materials that may accessible but not searchable.

Remember that much more will be available in the local language and in the actual vicinity. "[Bayerischer Landesverein für Familienkunde e.V.](http://www.blf-online.de/)" (BLF)" has publications and forums that may be relevant. A [Worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=passau+kirchham&qt=results_page) search returns, among others, "Kirchhamer Heimatbuch: auf der Grundlage der Chronik von Kirchham bis 1945" and "1200 Jahre Kirchham : Zu d. Feierlichkeiten vom 2.-10. Juli 1977." At GoogleBooks: [Statistische Beschreibung des Bisthums Passau, 1867, p. 71](https://books.google.ca/books?id=40JBAAAAcAAJ&dq=kirchham&pg=PA71#v=onepage&q=kirchham&f=false) says that the parish of Kirchham includes the village of Kirchham (41 houses with 325 inhabitants), and, outside Kirchham, among others, the place "Angerloh" (1 house with 9 inhabitants).

**Final comments**
Angloh may always have been small, and a local name for a crossroads or a farmhouse. Or it may have been a thriving village or town before war or pestilence depopulated it (a frequent occurrence in Bavaria). If the former, you may never get much additional information.

Also, by definition, a surname referencing a past residence was acquired AFTER moving elsewhere. Depending on the era that occurred, there may not be a record documenting it. If the surname is actually a farm-name, then any family living there may have taken on (or been known as) that name, without necessarily being related to the previous residents.

Comment: Im sorry it took so long but wanted to thank you ever so much for all the advise and instruction.

Comment: The original Document i had found was in Genwiki somewhere. It did list the location as a farm cluster of sorts. That is to say there was some deal made between the original owner and the next where the price of owning it was a certain measure of taking care of them with a place to live and food and coal. A typical agreement within family members and/or strangers for the time. The location is still listed as an addressable location. But I am looking around with the resources you gave me and again am grateful for your direction.

Answer (score 3):

[bgwiehle provided a great answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/9825/19) that might help with research for other small places as well.

Some additions to *Angloh*. GOV (an gazetteer) lists [Angloh](http://gov.genealogy.net/item/show/ANGLOH_W8399) as an “Einöd”. This means *by definition* just one or two residential houses, [see e.g. German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einzelsiedlung). Such places were (and are) common especially in southern Germany. Sometimes they vanished with the death of the last one living there and the name referred to a place without any housing until someone else settled there later. There might also have been several places named *Angloh* and there is no written tradition for the others (please note that most German surnames date back to the medieval ages).

Comment: Also thank you ever so much for all the guidance.